# Merge edges by distance in center?

Tags: modeling, edges, loop

I have been working on a mirrored mesh. Now I want to apply the mirror modifier and sew the middle edge loop of the mesh together by selecting it and merging the faces by distance.
So I choose Merge by Distance with the faces selected:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I expected was for the faces to stitch directly in the centerpoint between them, as is the case when I merge vertices by distance.
However,  what I got was an asymmetric line, which I don't want in this case; I want an edge loop running perfectly down the center of the model.

Is there a workaround here besides selecting all the vertex pairs across the center line from each other and merging them individually?

Comment: Hello :). It does merge in center. But your selection isn't perfectly symmetrical along the centerline. No problem, just scale it's width to 0 and move it to center.

Comment: Thank you! Selecting the loop and scaling its width on the x-axis to 0 solved this for me.